# Angular Batarang for apps that do not use ng-app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angularjs

I'm trying to use the Angular Batarang Chrome Extension for debugging an application based on AngularJS.

We are not using the `ng-app="foo"` attribute to bootstrap the application, but are rather calling doing a manual bootstrap (see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap):

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['foo']);
```

When enabling Batarang for this app in Chrome's developer tab, the application reloads as expected, but the *Models* tab doesn't show any *scopes*. I can highlight scopes through Batarang's *Options* tab, but the *Models* tab doesn't seem to work for this kind of application.

Has anybody experienced something similar? Is there a log where I can see potential Batarang errors? Is there a way to debug Batarang's code in Chrome? I checked the *Source* tab in Chrome, but it doesn't show Batarang's source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that one of our developers forgot to wrap the call to `angular.bootstrap()` in the `ready()` function.

Including the following in the main `index.html` file makes the application work fine in *Batarang*:

```
<script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['foo']);
    });
</script>
```